# iPerf UDP no loss but Client/Server bandwidth don't match?

Tags: networking, performance, bandwidth, iperf

No major loss of datagram occured, but the server bandwidth is extremely low, and don't match the client side, why?

Client command: iperf3 -c 10.255.0.2 -p 5001 -t 10 -i 5 -l 60k -u -b 15G

```
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Total Datagrams
[  4]   0.00-5.00   sec  4.22 GBytes  7.25 Gbits/sec  73772
[  4]   5.00-10.00  sec  4.28 GBytes  7.35 Gbits/sec  74757
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Jitter    Lost/Total Datagrams
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  8.50 GBytes  7.30 Gbits/sec  0.023 ms  127209/135772 (94%)
[  4] Sent 135772 datagrams
```

Server command: iperf3 -s -p 5001 -i 5

```
Accepted connection from 10.0.0.2, port 36610
[  6] local 10.255.0.2 port 5001 connected to 10.0.0.2 port 47969
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Jitter    Lost/Total Datagrams
[  6]   0.00-5.00   sec   332 MBytes   557 Mbits/sec  0.005 ms  64447/70114 (92%)
[  6]   5.00-10.00  sec   170 MBytes   285 Mbits/sec  0.023 ms  62762/65658 (96%)
[  6]  10.00-10.04  sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec  0.023 ms  0/0 (0%)
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Jitter    Lost/Total Datagrams
[  6]   0.00-10.04  sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec  0.023 ms  127209/135772 (94%)
```